# Hibernate mysql utf8 configuration

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, utf-8

I am using hibernate 4.1.4, mysql connector is 5.1.6. Hibernate  and tomcat server.xml connector configuration are below. When I try to save I got that exception. Whats the wrong?

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9Fekk\xC3...'`

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

`<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/*****?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">***</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>`

Comment: what is ***** value ??

Comment: Thats my db name,username and passwords. No problem wit thats @Mahi

Comment: try utf-8 in connection url

Comment: connection url also has utf-8  is taht wrong? `jdbc:mysql://localhost/whatever?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8<`

Comment: instead of utf8 try utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Hex `C58F` is `ş` in utf8/utf8mb4 encoding.

In the Hibernate configuration, I think it is spelled with a dash:  `UTF-8`.

See also https://docs.jboss.org/exojcr/1.12.13-GA/developer/en-US/html/ch-db-configuration-hibernate.html